# Minio Production Setup

Tags: minio

I'm considering to perform a Minio on-prem setup and started wondering the pros and cons of having Minio deployed on VMs vs K8S operator.

Since I couldn't find any comparison (or experience sharing) on Google, I raising this topic here for any comments or additions.

Really appreciate any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

VM or K8s, either way you're dealing with virtualization. The pros and cons of those don't have much to do with MinIO - MinIO has a Kubernetes Operator you can leverage for deploying onto K8s, or you can use some other VM-orchestration tooling out there - entirely up to you.

From a MinIO perspective, what really matters is ensuring you have the proper hardware components in place. Most important to performance is going to be network, storage controller, and storage (typically in that order). then CPU/Memory. Whether or not there is a virtualization layer doesn't *really* change much there - though I am aware of some issues with things like virtual network layers causing all kinds of problems, that's also outside of MinIO's purview.

We have some guidance [here](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/operations/checklists/hardware.html#production-hardware-requirements?ref=stackoverflow) on production hardware guidance and sizing. Might be a good place to start.

More specific than that is really situation dependent - it requires taking into account your intended storage, growth targets, performance targets, things like that. The only thing I can think of that really differs from OnPrem to VMs or K8s is that with VMs/K8s you have to consider resource contention if you are using your worker nodes for a lot of workloads. It's no different than running a bunch of high-perf services on a baremetal node - if you don't have sufficient IO to handle what you throw at your services, your services will not perform.

This is all kinda vague, but that's how it goes - you have the docs above, MinIO's own [reference hardware](https://min.io/product/reference-hardware?ref=stackoverflow), and whatever you can get by reaching out directly.